# Find the limit of $\lim_{ x\to 14} \frac{x^2-14x}{x^2-196}$

Tags: calculus

Find the following limit when  $$\lim_{ x\to 14} \frac{x^2-14x}{x^2-196}$$ I have find that subbing in 14 gives a null answer. But am having trouble factorizing this equation

Comment: Try L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: @Kevin it's too overboard.

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{x^2-14x}{x^2-196}=\dfrac{x(x-14)}{(x-14)(x+14)}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^2-14x}{x^2-196}=\frac{x(x-14)}{(x+14)(x-14)}={x\over x+14}$$ Then you will find the limit$={14\over28}={1\over2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2-14x=x(x-14)\text{ and } x^2-196=x^2-14^2=(x-14)(x+14)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since x tends to 14 and when you replace x with 14 you get 0/0 condition. Apply L'hospital rule i.e. differentiate both numerator and denominator w.r.t. x. Apply the limit and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: when $x \neq 14$ we have
$$
\frac{x^2-14x}{x^2-196} = \frac{x(x-14)}{(x+14)(x-14)} = \frac{x}{x+14}.
$$